# Access to iPhone music library

Tags: iphone

I'm planning to develop kind of DJ application which loads musics from music library.
And of course it'll sell in app store.

So question is, does it possible distribute in AppStore?

I found it was forbidden at least about 6 month ago...
But I hope it is possible now...

Comment: any update on this for iOS 5?

Answer (score 13):

In iPhone OS 2.x you can't access the music transferred to the phone via iTunes. You only have access to the data created by your own application.

The forthcoming version 3.0 does have this capability. [Release notes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOSv3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008245-SW4) include this

> **iPod Library Access**
>
> Several new classes and protocols have
>   been added to the Media Player
>   framework (MediaPlayer.framework) to
>   allow access to the user’s audio
>   library. You can use these classes to
>   perform the following tasks:
>
> - Play audio items from the user’s library. This support lets you play
>     all audio types supported by the iPod
>     application.
> - Construct queues of audio items to play back.
> - Perform searches of the user’s audio library.
> - Access the user’s playlists (including smart, on-the-go, and
>     genius playlists).
>
> For more information about the classes
>   of the Media Player framework, see
>   [Media Player Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952).

*(sorry,links may only be working for registered Apple developers).*

Comment: Thank you Paul.
So it is impossible what I wanted...
I try to realize in another way.

Comment: Does anyone know of actual documentation on how to do this, beyond the MP Framework Reference?  Like an actual example?  I did not find the API docs to be overly helpful since there are no examples provided.

Comment: iPod Library Access didn't quite live up to the hype. Yes, you could search the library, display album art, but as for manipulating the audio, well... you can play, stop or pause one track.

Answer (score 5):

In version 3.0 of the iPhone SDK you now have access to the music library.

Answer (score 3):

The SDK 3.0's Media Library Framework only allows you the most basic iPod controls over the music. You can't even output the .mp3 and work on it yourself (with OpenAL etc.).

So basically, its control can be only as capable as the iPod's, which is far too limited for any DJ applications.

Otherwise I would dream making the most amazing portable DJ device in the history of turntablism, ever. Hope we see that coming in SDK 3.1.

Comment: Not present in 3.1.2. The Media Layer Framework is worse than useless without access to the audio file. As of January 2010 you can still only play, stop or pause a single iPod track. If you could create an AVAudioPlayer with MPMediaItem you might salvage something, but no...

Answer (score 2):

Just putting it out there:

If you want to use PrivateFrameworks and make an app for the hell of it, then there is a Private Framework called MusicLibrary.

Answer (score 1):

To create a DJ application, won't you need the ability to load multiple songs at once then play over the top of each other?

As far as I know, the SDK only allows you to load 1 track at a time.