# How to browse and upload music file from iPhone Music Library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipod-touch

Is there any possible way to browse and upload music file from iPhone music library?

I m trying to browse music file from iPhone/iPod Music library through UiWebView...
But no success...
Thanks....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to iPhone music library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625625/access-to-iphone-music-library)

Comment: i want to do same.. if you solve your problem then share you code.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not possible through a web view, and not really doable with the actual SDK either. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to upload music file from iPhone Music library on my web Server Can you tell how to do it ????